# Need help fixing/clarifying my thinking about iid RVs after learning some 1st Yr Stats

Tags: probability, independence

> First a warning: this is not the most interesting question but I want to update my understanding of independence now that I'm taking 1st year statistics

- I often heard in my 1st year probability class that "independent RVs don't give any information about each other"
- Rolling a fair dice $99$ times doesn't give info on the hundredth roll
- However, let's say $X_1, ..., X_{100}$ are iid discrete uniform from $1$ to $\theta$ which is unknown
- Then by observing $X_1,...,X_{99}$ you can make inferences about the hundredth observation and make a prediction interval
- Is it safe to say that: given you know all the parameters or complete pmf/pdf of $F$, independent RVs don't give any information about each other. However, given that there are unknown parameters, **independent RVs do give you information about each other.** Does that make sense to even say?

I know this is more of an English question versus formal definitions (splitting pmfs/pdfs) but I'd like to try and be precise about this. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: This is basically the question of whether you are taking a frequentist or Bayesian approach to modeling your dice rolls.  Do you think of the unknown parameter as "determined but not known to you", or "random"?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  In the case when $\{X_1, ..., X_{100}\}$ all depend on a common random variable $\theta$ then you can say they are _conditionally_ i.i.d. given $\theta$, but they are not i.i.d. because they all depend on the random  $\theta$. [edit: In view of the above comment, you can say I am taking a "Bayesian" approach to interpreting $\theta$ itself as a random variable.]

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the info... I'm aware of the Frequentist vs Bayesian debate but I'm not at a level to fully appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the Nate Eldredge comment on two different views of the unknown $\theta$.

1) If $\theta$ is a random variable then you can say $\{X_1, ..., X_{100}\}$ are *conditionally* i.i.d. given $\theta$, but they are not i.i.d. because they all depend on the common random variable $\theta$. This is the "Bayesian" view of $\theta$.

2) If $\theta$ is a fixed (but possibly unknown) constant then indeed you can say $\{X_1, ..., X_{100}\}$ are i.i.d. because
\begin{align}
&P[X_1\leq x_1, ..., X_{100}\leq x_{100}] \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{100}P[X_i\leq x_i] \quad \forall (x_1, ..., x_{100}) \in \mathbb{R}^{100} \quad (Eq. 1)
\end{align}
It can be shown that (Eq. 1) implies
$$ E[h(X_{100})|X_1,...,X_{99}]=E[h(X_{100})] \quad (Eq. 2)$$
for all (measurable) functions $h$. 
**The equations (Eq. 1) and (Eq. 2) hold regardless of whether or not the value $\theta$ is known.**  In particular, the expressions in (Eq. 1)-(Eq. 2) may depend on $\theta$, but the expressions exist (and the left-hand-sides are equal to the right-hand-sides)  regardless of whether or not $\theta$ is known/unknown to an observer.

You can indeed interpret the Equations (1)-(2) to mean "the variables provide no information about each other": Knowing the outcomes of $X_1, ..., X_{99}$ does not change probabilities or expectations that involve only $X_{100}$.  Of course, those probabilities/expectations are themselves unknown if $\theta$ is not known.  So at a "higher level" you can indeed say that $X_1, ..., X_{99}$ gives "information" about the unknown $\theta$ and hence "information" about $X_{100}$.  For example, if we observe $X_{99}=207$ then we know it is possible for $X_{100}>200$. However, this does not change $P[X_{100}>200]$ because that probability itself depends on $\theta$. **It is difficult to quantify what "information" means without taking the "Bayesian" approach of treating the unknown $\theta$ itself as a random variable.**

On the other hand, there are some interesting things that can be said about $\theta$ when we just treat it as a constant (not a random variable), such as mean-square-error of approximating $\theta/2$: If $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. uniform over $[0,\theta]$ then 
$$ E\left[\left(\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2\right] = \frac{Var(X_1)}{n} = \frac{\theta^2}{12 n}$$
Of course this bound itself depends on $\theta$, but if we somehow know that $\theta \leq 100$ then we can say the mean-square-error is no more than $100^2/(12n)$.

---

Here is an estimator of $\theta$ with an improved mean-square-error:   Define
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}_n &= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\\
\tilde{\theta}_n &= \max\left\{\hat{\theta}_n, X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\right\}
\end{align}
It can be shown that (surely): 
$$ (\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta)^2 \leq (\hat{\theta}_n -\theta)^2$$
and so
$$ E\left[\left(\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta\right)^2\right] \leq E\left[\left(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta\right)^2\right] = \frac{\theta^2}{3n}$$
Some useful notes on other improvements are here:

http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~dsmall/stat512-s05/notes2.doc

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael and clearly pointing out the distinction when the unknown parameter is a RV or a fixed constant.

Comment: I also appreciate your insight on the language part of "information." In regards to your final comment, when $\theta$ is a constant for iid uniform discrete... it seems like you're saying that the bound for MSE is pretty good and so if $n$ is large then you can have a high confidence level on approximating the expected value... and so a big $n$ means that the iid RVs give you a lot of "information" about future values... is that the right way to think about it?

Comment: Yes, "confidence" is a good word.  I added a paragraph in my answer on a simple improved estimator of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael, I appreciate it! Yes I remember the discrete uniform was used as an example in my course of a distribution where the typical sample mean is not the best estimator which I thought was interesting

Comment: My calculations of $\theta^2/(3n)$ are for the continuous uniform case, based on $E[X_1]=\theta/2$, $Var(X_1) = \theta^2/12$.  Similar holds for the discrete uniform but the variance calculation is a bit different.

Comment: Ah yes! You're right, I meant to say continuous uniform.